# API Invalid Credentials PostMan

Tags: php, api, laravel, postman

So I'm trying to test my post request through Postman, but I get invalid credentials. I'm using the basic auth and I have a table with one user which contains an email, and password. I can't find why this isn't working. I followed a tutorial which did exactly the same and it worked. This is the link I'm trying to post to - http://localhost:8000/api/posts. Of course when I take off the "auth.basic" it works. I didn't really know what to put in the Postman username and password, so I just entered the email and the password that I have in the users table in the database. I'm using Laravel 5.1

My controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth.basic', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]); 
}

public function index()
{

    //return Post::all();
    return Post::paginate(10);
}

public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);

    if(!$post)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => [
            'message' => 'Post does not exist'
            ]
        ], 404);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $post
    ],200);
}

public function store(PostRequest $request)
{

}
```

Routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
});
```

Comment: Solved it. I just registered a user manually through Laravel auth system instead of seeding it. Don't know why it didn't work with the seed.